# Firebase web database - how to check whether a node exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to check in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) whether a particular node i.e. users exist ?

Comment: Did you try `.childexists`  function using `.equalTo("users")`?

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan, child means the descendant of a node, right ? I am trying to test the existence of the node i.e. parent of the child.

Comment: Yes, child means the descendant of a node.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan, then how would `.childexists` serve the purpose?

Comment: It doesn't for the parent/root one.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan, so what is to be done ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131997/discussion-between-akhter-alamin-farhan-and-istiaque-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function will work using js:

```
function searchKeyValue() {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
  if(ref)
  {
     var nextref=ref.child("users");
  }


}
```

Comment: This will not work. A reference always exists, so the if will always execute.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, does  any method exist for the purpose ?